Why does this lead to a contradiction. Big-O notation and asymptotic power of functions.
This isn't a typical MSE question. So I was sort of playing around with something. It's very similar to big-$\mathcal{O}$ notation. The following are the definitions, terminology, notation I made and some properties I've found. Then, I apply this to a specific case and I get a contradiction. I don't know where I went wrong and am wondering if someone could point it out, even in the comments, then I will consider this closed.

Definitions
Original definition (kinda deprecated because the other definition is all I really need):

Let $f,g$ be functions on $\mathbb{R}_{[c,\infty)}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. We call $f$ superior to $g$ if there exist no $a,N\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $ag(n)>f(n)\quad\forall n>N$. We represent this as $\displaystyle f>_{\infty}g$. We call $f$ to be inferior to $g$ if there exist no $a,N\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $af(n)>g(n)\quad\forall n>N$. We represent this as $f<_{\infty}g$. If $f$ is neither superior nor inferior to $g$, we say that $f$ and $g$ are asymptotically equal. We represent this as $f=_{\infty}g$.

The following are equivalent to the above:
$$\begin{align*}
&f>_{\infty}g \iff \displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=\infty\\
&f<_{\infty}g \iff \displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=0\\
&f=_{\infty}g \quad\text{otherwise}
\end{align*}$$
Properties
Now we have the following relationships:
$$\begin{align*}
&C\times f=_{\infty}f\\
&f=g\implies f=_{\infty}g\quad(f\neq_{\infty}g\implies f\neq g\text{ contrapositive})\\
&f>_{\infty}g\iff g<_{\infty}f\\
&f=_{\infty}g\iff g=_{\infty}f\\
&f=_{\infty}g,\hspace{1mm}g=_{\infty}h\implies f=_{\infty}h\\
&f>_{\infty}g,\hspace{1mm}g>_{\infty}h\implies f>_{\infty}h\\
\end{align*}$$
And slightly more fancy ones:
$$
\begin{align*}
&f>_{\infty}g\iff f+g=_{\infty}f\\
&f=_{\infty}g\iff f+g=_{\infty}f=_{\infty}g\\
&f=_{\infty}g\iff \frac{1}{f}=_{\infty}\frac{1}{g}\\
&f>_{\infty}g\iff \frac{1}{f}<_{\infty}\frac{1}{g}\\
&f=_{\infty}g\iff f\times h=_{\infty}g\times k,\quad h=_{\infty}k\\
\end{align*}
$$

Application
Now definitions are done, I'm applying this.
$\frac{3x+1}{(x-1)(x^{2}+1)}$ and $\frac{2}{x-1}+ \frac{1-2x}{x^{2}+1}$ are the same function, just graph them in desmos.
First we'll look at the asymptotic behaviour of $f(x)=\frac{3x+1}{(x-1)(x^{2}+1)}$. Firstly:
$$f(x)=\frac{3x}{x^{3}-x^{2}+x-1}+ \frac{1}{x^{3}-x^{2}+x-1}$$
Let the left term be $g(x)$ and the right term be $h(x)$.
$$g(x)=_{\infty}\frac{x}{x^{3}}=\frac{1}{x^{2}}$$
And:
$$h(x)=_{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{3}}$$
So $h<_{\infty}g$ (because $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n^{3}}}{\frac{1}{n^{2}}}=\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$), so:
$$\begin{align*}
f&=_{\infty}g+h\\
&=_{\infty}g\\
&\boxed{=_{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{2}}}\\
\end{align*}$$
Ok cool. Now we'll look at the asymptotic behaviour of $k(x)=\frac{2}{x-1}+ \frac{1-2x}{x^{2}+1}$. As before, let the left term be $g(x)$ and the right term be $h(x)$.
$$g(x)=_{\infty}\frac{1}{x}$$
And:
$$h(x)=_{\infty} \frac{x}{x^{2}}= \frac{1}{x}$$
So $g=_{\infty}h=_{\infty} \frac{1}{x}$, so:
$$\begin{align*}
k&=_{\infty}g+h \\
&=_{\infty}g\\
&\boxed{=_{\infty} \frac{1}{x}}
\end{align*}$$
And so $f<_{\infty}k\implies f\neq_{\infty}k\implies f\neq k$. But they are the same function.

The issue you are encountering here is analogous to the following situation, which may be more familiar and hence easier to digest:
If $R=\mathbb C[x]$ is the ring of complex-valued polynomials in one variable,  the degree function $\mathrm{deg}(p)$ gives the highest power of $x$ occuring with a non-zero coefficient in $p$, thus $\mathrm{deg}\colon R\backslash \{0\} \to \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$.
The degree function has an easy compatibility with multiplication, in that
$$
\tag{$*$}
\mathrm{deg}(f_1.f_2) = \mathrm{deg}(f_1) + \mathrm{deg}(f_2), \quad \forall f_1,f_2 \in R.
$$
What is a little more subtle is its relation to addition: if $f_1,f_2 \in R$ then if $\mathrm{deg}(f_1) \neq \mathrm{deg}(f_2)$ it follows that
$$
\mathrm{deg}(f_1+f_2) = \max(\mathrm{deg}(f_1), \mathrm{deg}(f_2)).
$$
However, if $\mathrm{deg}(f_1)= \mathrm{deg}(f_2)$ then all that can be said is that
$$
\tag{$**$}
\mathrm{deg}(f_1+f_2) \leq \mathrm{deg}(f_1) = \mathrm{deg}(f_2)
$$
since it may happen the the leading coefficients of $f_1$ and $f_2$ cancel each other resulting in $f_1+f_2$ having strictly lower degree than either $f_1$ or $f_2$. Thus, if we are given arbitrary $f_1,f_2 \in R$ the most one can say about the relationship between the degree of a sum and the degrees of its summands is the inequality($*$). (The properties $(*)$ and $(**)$ characterize what are known as valuations on an algebra).
What happens with the asymptotics of $f$ and $k$ is analogous to the above: indeed the degree function extends to rational functions in $x$ by setting $\mathrm{deg}(p/q) = \mathrm{deg}(p)-\mathrm{deg}(q)$, and the relation $\leq_
\infty$, when restricted to rational functions, is simply $\mathrm{deg}(f_1)\leq \mathrm{deg}(f_2)$
The apparent contradiction you encountered can now be seen as an example of where the leading terms cancel: both terms in the expression $k=\frac{2}{x-1} + \frac{1-2x}{x^2+1}$ have order $x^{-1}$, but when you add them the highest order terms cancel, meaning that $k$ has order $x^{-2}$.

Oh so my error was in assuming $f={\infty}g\iff f+g={\infty}f={\infty}g$, which is actually false if $\displaystyle\lim{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=-1$ (because then they cancel out), in which case $f+g$ is inferior to $f$. This and @Mike 's answer really helped, thank you.

Yes exactly! Missing the possibility of cancellation seems to be exactly what made it appear that there was an inconsistency.

You have to be careful, there is a reason why $a$ in your definition is required to be in $\mathbb{N}$ [as opposed to being allowed to be any integer in $\mathbb{Z}$ [or even any nonzero integer]] and thus $a$ is thus required to be positive.
Anyways, in fact the following is true instead:  $$\frac{1-2x}{x^2+1} \not =_{\infty} \frac{1}{x}.$$
Why the "not equals" in the above relation? Well, there is no natural number $a$ such that the inequality $a \Big(\frac{1-2x}{x^2+1}\Big) \ge \frac{1}{x}$ holds $\forall x$ sufficiently large. Why not? Well the quantity on the left, for large enough $x$, is negative, so multiplying by any positive number will keep it negative, and thus less than $\frac{1}{x}$ which is positive for all positive $x$.
[However, yes indeed,
$$\Big|\frac{1-2x}{x^2+1}\Big| =_{\infty} \frac{1}{x}.$$ Can you see the difference.]
You may want to play around with a few examples: Take for example, $f$ such that $f(x)=1 \ \forall x$ i.e., $f$ is a constant function. Then $f(x) \not =_{\infty} x^2$, even though $f(x)$ can be written $f(x) = (1+x^2) - x^2$.

Perhaps really a "comment", but, perhaps resolving-by-reframing your question:
Yes, "math" is often a very good book-keeping system, a narrative, for things happening in physics and engineering situations. Much of its utility derives from its (apparent) internal/self-consistency. Ok.
Also, "math" narrative is a very useful "accounting" tool/device. Ok.
Yes, in some (useful/interesting) cases the notation/language that is completely good as narrative or accounting is stretched beyond its "confirmed operating range". No, for novices it is not easy to understand the limits here.
So, without directly addressing the problems in the question, I'm not at all surprised that naive expressions about asymptotics can lead to nonsense...
So, unless we declare that math is inconsistent, or that the external world is self-contradictory somehow... the point is that ideas about asymptotics must have been mis-used here.
Yes, it is certainly true that mainstream math is naive about "asymptotic expansions", and, then, while many heuristics yield correct outcomes, not_all will do so.
Is your question really about asymptotic expansions?

Well, if you ignore the word 'asymptotics' and just use the limit expressions as definitons. Limits are well-defined on the domains I am using, so where did I misuse them? I'm almost certain I did misuse them somewhere but I can't find where.

@TymonMieszkowski, I cannot look at this today, but I will look at it tomorrow.
